# How can I change a column's data type and then perform actions against that new type in the same script in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a script with an `Alter Column` statement that's changing the data type from a `Bigint` to a `Varchar`. Immediately afterwards, I need to call `Substring()` on that column.

Unfortunately, the syntax checker of SQL Server won't let me do this. I need to add a 'GO' statement to split the commands. The problem with this is, I also need to include `IF`-conditions in my script, and adding a `GO` statement will break the `IF` block so it no longer exists in the same scope and breaks the logic of my code.

Is there any way to do this:

```
Alter Table MyTable
Alter Column MyColumn varchar(25)

GO

Update MyTable
Set MyColumn = Substring(MyColumn, 0, 5)
```

Without using the word `GO`?

Comment: Are you absolutely certain you need to alter that table? Why not convert BigInt to Varchar and then use the substring on that?

Comment: I definitely need to alter the table. I have no way of getting out of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
Alter Table MyTable
Alter Column MyColumn varchar(25)

EXEC('Update MyTable
Set MyColumn = Substring(MyColumn, 0, 5)');
```